# Convert string to given regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

How to convert the `string` into the *given pattern*. Consider pattern can be anything.

Example:

- Input String is - `1234567890`
- For Pattern `XXXX-XXXX-XX` Then Output is - `1234-5678-90`
- For Pattern `XXX-XXX-XXX-X` Then Output is - `123-456-789-0`
- For Pattern `XXX=XXX=XXX=X` Then Output is - `123=456=789=0`
- For Pattern `XX-XXX-X-XXXX` Then Output is - `12-345-6-7890`

Note: Length of input string may vary.

I have tried as

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("1235645847", ".{1,4}", "$&-").TrimEnd('-'));
```

But it is *not dynamic* it's working for the *first pattern only*.

Is it possible to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, it _is_ possible to achieve. If you post, what you have tried, people tend to give you better answers.

Comment: If you are not familiar with regular expression, go have a read https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: StackOverflow is _not_ a code-writing service. Show us what you have done so far and what is your problem? Btw, as for me, `XXXXXXXXX*X` pattern should produce `123456789*0`, no?

Comment: I have included the same pattern but * is creating issues while displaying so changed to "="

Comment: This is not a question about pattern matching or regular expressions.  This is a formatting question.  Please edit your tags and provide a minimum set of code that demonstrates what you are trying to do so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

As already said, this is question has nothing in common with regex. Well, except pattern, but you using it in diferent context. You need just to format some strings, using some pattern.

You could use this function for example:

```
public string ConvertToFormat(string strToFormat, string pattern)
{
  if (pattern.Count(c => c == 'X') != strToFormat.Length)
    throw new ArgumentException("Number of placeholders in pattern is different from number of characters in the input string!");
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
    if (pattern[i] == 'X')
    {
      sb.Append(strToFormat[j]);
      j++;
    }
    else
      sb.Append(pattern[i]);

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

and use like this:

```
string result = ConvertToFormat("1234567890", "XXXX-XXXX-XX");
result = ConvertToFormat("1234567890", "XXX-XXX-XXX-X");
result = ConvertToFormat("1234567890", "XXX=XXX=XXX=X");
```

**UPDATE**

Dynamic solution with regtex:

```
public string RegexConvertToFormat(string strToFormat, int blockSize, char separator)
{
  return Regex.Replace("1235645847", ".{" + blockSize + "}" , "$&" + separator).TrimEnd(separator);
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = RegexConvertToFormat("1234567890", 4, '-');
s = RegexConvertToFormat("1234567890", 3, '-');
s = RegexConvertToFormat("1234567890", 3, '=');
```

Comment: Michal, I have tried a similar solution this is definitely a good way. But is this same possible with Regex.

Comment: @SumitDeshpande This is not appropriate task for regex, it cannot be done with it.

Comment: Yes this is working but I am looking for blocksize as dynamic. Ex. XX-XXX-X-XX.

Comment: @SumitDeshpande Well, it could be done with regex, but it would be the worst method to accomplish it. The best you could do is supply array of indexes where separators have to be inserted.

Answer (score 3):

```
string input="123456789";
var pattern="XXX-XXX=XXX";

var reg=new Regex(new string('N',input.Length).Replace("N","(\\w)"));//1.
var regX=new Regex("X");
for (int i = 1; i <= input.Length; i++)
{
    pattern=regX.Replace(pattern,"$"+i.ToString(),1);//2.
}
Console.WriteLine( reg.Replace(input,pattern));
```

[image]

1. replace input `123456789` to `(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)` multi groups

2. replace pattern `XXX-XXX=XXX` to groups replacement `$1$2$3-$4$5$6=$7$8$9`

Answer (score 1):

A simple *Linq* will do:

```
public static string ApplyPattern(string value, string mask) {
  if (null == value)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
  else if (null == mask)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("mask");
  else if (mask.Count(c => c == 'X') != value.Length)
    throw new ArgumentException("Inconsistent mask", "mask"); 

  int index = 0;

  // index++ - side effect - which is, however, safe in the context
  return string.Concat(mask
    .Select(c => c == 'X' ? value[index++] : c));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string[] testMasks = new string[] {
  "XXXX-XXXX-XX",
  "XXX-XXX-XXX-X",
  "XXX=XXX=XXX=X",
  "XX-XXX-X-XXXX",
  "+XX-=XXX-X--XXXX",
  "+(XX)=XXX-X--XXXX?",
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, testMasks
  .Select(mask => $"{mask,20} -> {ApplyPattern("1234567890", mask)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
XXXX-XXXX-XX         -> 1234-5678-90
XXX-XXX-XXX-X        -> 123-456-789-0
XXX=XXX=XXX=X        -> 123=456=789=0
XX-XXX-X-XXXX        -> 12-345-6-7890
+XX-=XXX-X--XXXX     -> +12-=345-6--7890
+(XX)=XXX-X--XXXX?   -> +(12)=345-6--7890?
```